# Need to parse data in bash

Tags: bash

The following is the format of data that I need to parse in bash. Assuming that a bash variable holds this data, I need to be able to extract the value in `xyz`. Further, I need to be able to also extract `aa` and `bb` individually from with `xyz`.

```
"params": {
    "children": [
           {
                "abc": {
                    "pp": "1234567890",
                    "qq": "a.b.c"
                },
                "xyz": {
                    "aa": "0987654321",
                    "bb": "c.b.a"
                },
                "def": "p.q.r"
            }
        ],
        "def": "e.f.g.h"
    }
```

Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: Use a JSON parser, _please_.

Comment: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: @devnull/@slayedbylucifer: I'm familiarizing myself with the json parsers. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk)

Answer (score 1):

The shell is not a good language for writing general parsers. That said, if your input format is more or less exactly as shown, with maximally one `"name": "value"` pair per line, try this:

```
$ eval $(sed -n 's/"\([^"]*\)"[ :]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1=\2/p' inputfile)
$ echo $aa
0987654321
$ echo $bb
c.b.a
```

Comment: What if I have 'aa' and 'bb' under both 'abc' and 'xyz'? How would I retrieve a specific line?

Comment: Then I suggest using a tool matching the problem, i.e. a proper parser, which the shell isn't.